# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method "GetUserById"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I've tried to do this (load some data from a db to send it by JSON) 
But I've catched an excpetion:

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Model.Models.User GetUserById(Int32)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression

How can I avoid this exception and get the `userId` which I needed for the each record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework tries to convert your query into SQL query. But it fails to convert `GetUserById` method call into SQL (no surprise here). You should move this part of linq query to client side:

```
var favList = context.FavoriteMessages
        .Where(m => m.UserId == user.UserId && m.OnlineRoomId == user.OnlineRoomId)
        .Select(m => new {
            m.UserId,   // return user id from database
            m.Instance,
            m.CreatedOn
        })
        .AsEnumerable() // further part of query is not translated into SQL
        .Select(i => new {
            UserName = userService.GetUserById(i.UserId).Name, // get name locally
            i.Instance,
            i.CreatedOn
        }).ToList();
```

But if you'll think about filtering part of your query, you'll see that you are selecting only messages which have userId equal to `user.UserId`. That means - all of selected messages will have same user id, and what is more important - that will be id of user which you already have. And even more - you already have name of user in `User.Identity.Name`. So, the query should look like:

```
var user = userService.GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name);
var favorites = from m in context.FavoriteMessages
                where m.UserId == user.UserId && m.OnlineRoomId == user.OnlineRoomId 
                select new {
                   UserName = user.Name,
                   m.Instance,
                   m.CreatedOn
                };

return Json(favorites.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I believe I don't need double LINQ selecting

Comment: Anyway, дзякуй, sir

Comment: yeap, that filter is needed over there. I'm loading those messages only for one user, who've ever added a favorite message in the current room

Comment: @LabLab I have added improved version of query without additional userService call, немає за що :)

Comment: User.Identity.Name - it's a name of the current user who've sent a request to server (using ajax). And he can always add to `dbo.favorite_messages` the other user's messages too, so I need to get their names, instead of his own name

Comment: My apperciate for the more refactored version